# Is this a good way to process an order? (SQL+PHP)

Tags: php, sql

I'm making a simple webshop, it's not the full code, there are more security procedures. I'm just want to know your opinions. Thank you.

These SQL tables I have:

(I have more column in this table this is just an example)

**customers:**

| id | name | phone | address | zip | city | country | o_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Test | 12345 | Test Adress | 1234 | Test City | Test Country | 01-02-2022 |

**orders**

| customerid | orderid | orderdate | total_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OS1 | 01-02-2022 | 19 |

**orderitems**

| id | orderid | productid | item_price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | OS1 | P1 | 19 |

**shipping**

| orderid | shipping_method | shipping_price | tracking_id | status | sent_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| OS1 | courier | 0 | 12345 | sent | 02-01-2022 |

**products**

| product_id | productprice | currency | productqty | productname | weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| P1 | 19 | 19 | USD | 1 | Test Product |

You must have noticed that I have 3 times the price of the order/product in the tables. The reason why is in the **products** table I have the current product price this can be changed, and in the another tables I have the product price which was at the time of ordering.

After submitting the form the customer will land on this page:

**order.php**

```
/// Insert into customers table
    $data = [
        'name' => $name,
        'phone' => $phone,
        'adress' => $adress,
        'zip' => $zip,
        'city' => $city,
        'country' => $country,
        'o_date' => $date
    ];
    $sqlinsertcustomer = "INSERT INTO customers (id, name, phone, adress, zip, city, country, o_date ) VALUES ( '', :name, :phone, :adress, :zip, :city, :country, :o_date)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sqlinsertcustomer);
    $stmt->execute($data);
    $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
    $order_id = "OS". $last_id;
    
    /// Get the total price from the actual product. 
    
    $stmtpprice = $conn->prepare("SELECT productprice FROM products WHERE product_id = :product_id;");
    $stmtpprice->execute([":product_id"=>$productid]);
    $productprice = $stmtsms->fetch();
    $totalpprice = $productprice["productprice"];
    
/// Insert into Orders, Orderitems, Shipping Table
    $stmtorders = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (customerid, orderid, orderdate, total_price) VALUES (:customerid, :orderid, :orderdate, :total_price);");
    $stmtorderitems = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO orderitems (id, orderid, productid, item_price) VALUES ('', :orderid, :productid, :itemprice);");
    $stmtshipping = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO shipping (orderid, shipping_method, shipping_price, tracking_id, status, sent_date) VALUES (:orderid, :shipping_method, :shipping_price, '0', '0', :sent_date);");
    $stmtorders->execute([":customerid"=>$last_id,
                          ":orderid"=>$order_id,
                          ":orderdate"=>$date],
                          ":totalprice"=>$totalpprice]);
    $stmtorderitems->execute([":orderid"=>$order_id,
                              ":productid"=>$productid],
                              ":itemprice"=>$totalpprice]);
    $stmtshipping->execute([":orderid"=>$order_id,
                            ":shipping_method"=>$shippingmethod,
                            ":shipping_price"=>$shippingprice,
                            ":sent_date"=>$date]);
```

What do you thing about processing and about the table structure? Thank you!

Comment: In most of the tables you are consistent. The column names are unique. Why two columns "id" and not "item_id" and "cust_id". It is more of being consistent than anything else. I have found unique column names being easier to manage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some minor suggestions:

- I would move the code that retrieves the current product price to a dedicated function.
- The main code should be a standalone function too
- You should use a **transaction** to wrap up the whole sequence of operations, so that in case of error, you don't end up with inconsistent data and orphaned records.
- Separate the three blocks that write to tables Orders, Orderitems, Shipping Table.
- Add **spacing** where appropriate eg: `$stmtorderitems->execute([":orderid" => $order_id,...`
- Improve **naming** a little bit, for example `$last_id` should be `$customer_id` so that there is no misunderstanding.
- One potentially misleading statement: `$totalpprice` is the product price and not the total amount of the order as one might think. So just call it `$product_price` and there is no ambiguity.

---

```
$productprice = $stmtsms->fetch();
$totalpprice = $productprice["productprice"];
```

- The order ID is generated like this: `$order_id = "OS". $last_id;`. Why not simply use an ID as well ? A client may have more than one order...
- One problem in your code is that it requires **horizontal scrolling**, the SQL statement lines are too long. Wrap them up to have a better overview. I would perhaps do like this:

---

```
$stmtorders = $conn->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO orders (customerid, orderid, orderdate, total_price) 
    VALUES (:customerid, :orderid, :orderdate, :total_price);"
);
```

But you have considerable freedom here.

Answer (score 2):

Quick remarks:

- Your naming should be more consistent. You sometimes use snake_case (`item_price`) and elsewhere you simply compound words (`productid`). (I'd prefer PascalCase, but perhaps in your DB snake_case is more common. I'm not a fan of simply compounding words, it makes things unclear.)
- Use descriptive column names, I have no idea what `o_date` is supposed to be.
- No need to repeat information: `item_price` should just be `price`, since each entry is an item (in an order). Same with `product_id` and `productprice` in the table `products`.
- I'm a fan of having an ID in each table, even if each entry could be identified by a combination of columns. To me a combination of columns feels less like an ID, and more like a constraint. (But that's an opinion, others will possibly/likely disagree.)
- Don't needlessly abbreviate: you gain nothing by using `qty` instead of `quantity`.